# Determine the subgroup of $D_8$ generated by $r_4$ and $s_0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, solution-verification, dihedral-groups, cayley-table

I am wondering if my work for computing $\langle r_4 , s_0 \rangle$ in $D_8$ is correct.

Here $r$ denotes rotation of 45 degrees and $s$ denotes reflections about the lines of symmetries.

$D_8 = \{ r_0, r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4, r_5, r_6, r_7, s_0, s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4, s_5, s_6, s_7 \}$

Then $\langle r_4 \rangle = \{r_0, r_4 \}$ since $r_4 \circ r_4 = r_0$ and $\langle s_0 \rangle = \{ r_0, s_0 \}$ since $s_0 \circ s_0  = r_0$.

Then I use the following Caley table to compute $\langle r_4, s_0 \rangle.$

\begin{array}{c|cc}
\circ & r_0 & r_4 \\
\hline
r_0 & r_0 & r_4 \\
s_0 & s_0 & s_4
\end{array}

Thus, $\langle r_4, s_0 \rangle = \{ r_0, r_4, s_0, s_4 \}$

Comment: Rotating by 45 degree twice does not get you back where you started.

Comment: I think the $r_2$ in your 'Cayley table' should be $r_0$?

Comment: It was a typo. I replaced $r_2$ with $r_0$ in the first column. @TobiasKildetoft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a Cayley table in this way to 'compute' $\langle r_4,s_0\rangle$. You have multiplied a few elements from $\{r_0,r_4,s_0,s_4\}$ together, but what ensures you that you have all elements of $\langle r_4,s_0\rangle$?

Here's another approach: The subgroup $\langle r_4,s_0\rangle$ of $D_8$ is the smallest subgroup of $D_8$ containing both $r_4$ and $s_0$. Your calculation already show that
$$\{r_0,r_4,s_0,s_4\}\subset\langle r_4,s_0\rangle.$$
If you can show that $\{r_0,r_4,s_0,s_4\}$ is a subgroup of $D_8$ then it follows that
$$\langle r_4,s_0\rangle=\{r_0,r_4,s_0,s_4\}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: So, from here I just need to show that $\{ r_0, r_4, s_0, s_4 \}$ is a subgroup of $D_8$, i.e., show that this subset is closed under composition, associative, a unique identity exists, and that each element has an inverse?  @Servaes

Comment: Indeed. Note that associativity follows from the fact that $D_8$ is itself a group; you never need to check this for a subgroup.

Comment: Oh yeah, associativity is inherited from the group $D_8$.  Thank you very much for your help!